# Interface exposes an event and a method with the same name

Tags: c#, events, interface

I have a vendor supplied out-of-process Com interface. 
Within this interface is a method

```
ContextChangedEx(String xmlStuff)
```

and an event

```
ContextChangedEx.
```

They look to be from two separate interfaces that the com object is implementing.

When I try to subscribe to this event with

```
eventObject.ContextChangedEx += eventObject_ContextChangeEx;
```

I get an error:

```
ContextChangeEx cannot be assigned because it is a method group.
```

I cannot change the vendor library, but need to subscribe to this event. How can I force it to look at the event instead of the method?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, since they are on different interfaces, casting the com event object to the correct interface fixes the problem.

```
((IEventHandlerEvent_Interface)eventObject).ContextChangedEx += eventObject_ContextChangedEx
```

Comment: I was just writing the same answer that you gave to yourself.  ;-)